# DateTime difference in days on the basis of Date only

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I need to find the difference in days between two dates.

For example:

Input: `**startDate** = 12-31-2012 23hr:59mn:00sec, **endDate** = 01-01-2013 00hr:15mn:00sec`

Expected output: `1`

I tried the following:

1. `(dt1-dt2).TotalDays` and convert to integer but didn't give me appropriate answer as double has to be converted to int - tried Math.Ceiling, Convert.To...
2. `dt1.day - dt2.day` does not work across months
3. `dt.Substract()` has the same output as option 1 mentioned above.

None of the above worked, so I ended up writing the following code. The code works well, but I feel that there must be a solution with only a couple of lines of code.

```
public static int GetDifferenceInDaysX(this DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        //Initializing with 0 as default return value
        int difference = 0;

        //If either of the dates are not set then return 0 instead of throwing an exception
        if (startDate == default(DateTime) | endDate == default(DateTime))
            return difference;

        //If the dates are same then return 0
        if (startDate.ToShortDateString() == endDate.ToShortDateString())
            return difference;

        //startDate moving towards endDate either with increment or decrement
        while (startDate.AddDays(difference).ToShortDateString() != endDate.ToShortDateString())
        {
            difference = (startDate < endDate) ? ++difference : --difference;
        }

        return difference;
    }
```

Note: I do not have any performance issue in the while-loop iteration as the max difference will not be more than 30 to 45 days.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Well, it sounds like you want the difference in the number of days, ignoring the time component. A `DateTime` with the time component reset to 00:00:00 is what the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property gives you:

```
(startDate.Date - endDate.Date).TotalDays
```

Comment: Simple and straight forward. Just wondering how come I couldn't think of it... :((... Thanks Damien for a sweet line of code... :))

Answer (score 12):

If you use the `DateTime.Date` property this will eliminate the time

```
date1.Date.Subtract(date2.Date).Days
```

Comment: Sure Amiram, it works.. but already marked earlier post as the accepted answer.

Thanks for the participation.

Answer (score 3):

Use [TimeStamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx). Just subtract two dates (using [DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property), get the difference in time span and return [TotalDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx)

```
TimeSpan ts = endDate.Date - startDate.Date;
double TotalDays = ts.TotalDays;
```

So your extension method can be as simple as:

```
public static int GetDifferenceInDaysX(this DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
      return (int) (endDate.Date - startDate.Date).TotalDays;
      // to return just a int part of the Total days, you may round it according to your requirement
    }
```

**EDIT:** Since the question has been edited, you may check the following example. 
Consider the following two dates.

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2012, 12, 31, 23, 59, 00);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2013, 01, 01, 00, 15, 00);
```

You can write the extension method as:

```
public static int GetDifferenceInDaysX(this DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = endDate - startDate;
        int totalDays = (int) Math.Ceiling(ts.TotalDays);
        if (ts.TotalDays < 1 && ts.TotalDays > 0)
            totalDays = 1;
        else
            totalDays = (int) (ts.TotalDays);
        return totalDays;
    }
```

For the above dates it will give you 1

Comment: Habib, I think Damien_The_Unbeliever's approach is more elegant.